# Python - Maping is not defined

Tags: python, mapping

I am currently learning python and doing a moudle on mapping.

I seem to be getting an error in the terminal "NameError: name 'Maping' is not defined"

Sorry if this is a stupid question also.

Here is my code.

```
def square(num):
    return num ** 2
```

my_nums = [1,2,3,4]

```
for item in map(sqaure, my_nums):
    print(item)
```

Comment: Please check your code formatting to see if that's correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this helping you:

```
def square(num): 
    print(num ** 2)

my_nums = [1,2,3,4]

list(map(square, my_nums))
```

Output:

```
1
4
9
16
```

Or you can try this:

```
print([num**2 for num in my_nums])
# [1, 4, 9, 16]
```

Comment: Thank You !!! i just realised i spelt square wrong too. My bad. Much appreciated.

Comment: @CharlesBallantyne welcome, is this your answer? if this is your answer read this link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

I ran you code inside my environment . and it had no problem . in your code you wrote `sqaure` instead of `square` .

```
def square(num): return num ** 2
my_nums = [1,2,3,4]
for item in map(square, my_nums): print(item)
```

outputs:
1
4
9
16

Comment: Thank You !! Yes I stupidly realised this after after I had posted it and someone had already answered. Much appreciated

Comment: The output should be in separate line?  (instead of one line)